# Apache 2.4 host multiple Django project

Tags: django, apache, http-status-code-404, virtualhost

I would like to host multiple django projects on apache without touching hosts file or modify DNS entries. I cannot use named based virtual host setup as I cannot modify DNS entries nor hosts file.

Ideally, I would like to access each project like this
http://my.website.com/project1
http://my.website.com/project2

(If I am doing java project. With tomcat running war file, I can access each project as above.)

Is this possible? I am able to have server listen to different port and point to appropriate project, but that is not what I want. Any other way I can set up virtualhost in apache to access projects as described above?

My Filesystem structure:
c:/apache2.4 
c:/apache2.4/htdocs/www/MyDjangoApp/project1
c:/apache2.4/htdocs/www/MyDjangoApp2/project2
c:/python3.4

Spec: Windows 2012 R2 server, Apache 2.4 (64 bit) + mod_wsgi, Django 1.7, python 3.4 (64 bit)

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

So I added 127.0.0.1 my.website.com/project1 in windows etc/hosts file on the server and setup virtual host as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.website.com/project1    
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache2.4/htdocs/www/MyDjangoApp"
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Apache2.4/htdocs/www/MyDjangoApp/wsgi.py"
    <Directory "c:/Apache2.4/htdocs/www/MyDjangoApp">
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/project1-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project1-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I can actually goes to http://my.website.com/project1, but it will turn to 404 page from django instead of home page. The 404 page pulled up with all my static files (images and css) and it is my custom 404 page. Homepage will be up if I access via http://my.website.com/

It shoudl be Django cannot figure out where is the home page....?

Note: Without any virtual host setting, I can get to the actual page.

my url.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'project1.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'project1.views.login'),        
)
handler404 = 'project1.views.error404'
```

Any one has any idea why it wouldn't go to home page?

Thanks again!

Comment: You would set up one virtual host which has several RewriteRules, one for each of the "directories" you would serve from a specific Django instance. Each Django instance would probably need to run on its own port, 8000, 8001, etc.

Comment: What's wrong with `project1.website.com` and `project2.website.com`?

Comment: @dan-klasson project1.website.com will require me to use name-based virtual host, which I cannot do since I have no right to hosts file nor DNS

Comment: @dylrei no way they all run on the same port?

Comment: So by host file you mean apache v-host file.

Comment: @dan-klasson hosts file is under c:\windows\system32\driver\etc\hosts It is not the apache v-host file. I think I should say that I can modify local hosts file but that will never make it into DNS entries in the org.

Comment: @wolf97084 I don't know how things work on Windows... but if this were unix, they should be running on different ports. That's how you would know which instance you're talking to.

Comment: @wolf97084: why would you want to mess with the host file? i don't get it. this is a server no?

Comment: @dylrei I would really like to use the same port but just append different project name after the website address. You are correct, I was able to access different projects via diff port.

Comment: @dan-klasson when using name-based virtual host in apache, you usally will add entries in the etc/hosts file so the ip and name mapping will be recognized by remote users. I do not want to modify etc/hosts file. This server is one of several we have in the company

Comment: With Apache you can listen to port 80 and differentiate the calls by domains, or subdomains. So, for example, `project1.website.com` goes to one folder and `whatever.website.com` goes to another.

Comment: I believe the mapping of project1.website.com and its ip needs to be added in etc/hosts file. I don't need to add the mapping?